# Set focus on input field in modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set focus to an input field in a modal box but I can't get it to work.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
// MODAL BOX
$(function() {
    $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 100, closeButton: ".modal_close" }).find("#first-focus").focus();      
});
```

And

```
// MODAL BOX
$(function() {
    $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 100, closeButton: ".modal_close" }).find("input:text:visible:first").focus();      
});
```

Any suggestions on what I can try more?

Comment: I solved it with HTML5's autofocus attribute instead. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using correct method setFocus().

It works fine see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Luwfey9/)

It means you're probably missing the correct selector.
For the first tag `first-focus` is an id, so it can directly be called as `$('#first-focus').setFocus();`

The link that you've provided for [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEgrPr) is executing `setFocus()` method, which is not defined by jQuery. jQuery method is `focus()`. Apart from that this method is called only once. It should be called on click of `Open` link.

Your code would now become

```
// MODAL BOX
$(function() {
  $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({
    top: 100,
    closeButton: ".modal_close"
  }).click(function () {
    $('#first-focus').focus();
    console.log($("#first-focus").length);
  });
});
```

Here's a working [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKJEgq)

It would be best to call the `focus()` oncomplete callback of `leanModal` however I was unable to find such callback in the documentation or in the source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still can't get it to work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEgrPr

Comment: Please post your HTML code, that will help in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access directly to the element by `id`:

```
$("#first-focus").focus();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Waiting for the modal to load is a better UX, in my opinion.

Comment: I have tried that too, but it didn't work, sorry i forgot to mention that in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

```
$("a[rel*=leanModal]").on('click', function(){
  $(this).leanModal();
  $("#first-focus").focus(); 
})
```